# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' (python)

Tags: python, html

[image]

http://cs1.ucc.ie/~adc2/cgi-bin/lab7/index.html 
You can check out the error for yourself by just inputting anything into anyone of the boxes , doesnt have to be all, any help would be great
, I will send on the code after this

```
from cgitb import enable  
enable()

from cgi import FieldStorage,escape

print('Content-Type: text/html')  
print()


actor=''

genre=''

theyear=''

director=''

mood=''

result=''


form_data= FieldStorage()  
if len(form_data) != 0:  

    try:    
        actor=escape(form_data.getfirst('actor'))
        genre=escape(form_data.getfirst('genre'))
        theyear=escape(form_data.getfirst('theyear'))
        director=escape(form_data.getfirst('director'))
        mood= escape(form_data.getfirst('mood'))
        connection = db.connect('####', '###', '####', '###')
        cursor = connection.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("""SELECT title
                          FROM films
                          WHERE (actor = '%s')
                          OR (actor='%s' AND genre='%s')
                          OR (actor='%s' AND genre='%s' AND theyear='%i')
                          OR (actor='%s' AND genre='%s' AND theyear='%i' AND director='%s')
                          OR (actor='%s' AND genre='%s' AND theyear='%i' AND director='%s' AND mood='%s') % (actor, actor,genre, actor,genre,theyear, actor,genre,theyear,director,actor,genre,theyear,director,mood))
                          """)
        result = """<table>
                    <tr><th>Your movie!</th></tr>
                    <tr><th></th></tr>"""
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            result+= '<tr><td>%s</td></tr>' ,(row['title'])
        result+= '</table>'
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()




    except db.Error:
        result = '<p>Sorry! We are currently experiencing technical difficulties.</p>'
```

Comment: Well what is not clear about the error: you call `replace` so you prlbably assume that it is a `str`, but it is a `None`. So I think the input does not runs correctly through the API.

Comment: okay thank you , ive added the code there

Comment: I don't see a call to `str.replace()` in that code.  Please supply the full traceback in your question.

Comment: It's because you do not provide a **genre** in which case it is `None`. So you should replace `form_data.getfirst('genre')` with `form_data.getfirst('genre') or ''` (and do this with all similar lines)

Comment: `result+= '<tr><td>%s</td></tr>' ,(row['title'])` did you mean `result+= '<tr><td>%s</td></tr>' % (row['title'])` (replaced _comma_ by _percent_)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i added the or ' ' onto the end of each line but i continue to get the same error?

Comment: @AidanCronin: not **at the end**. **Inside the `escape(..)`**.

Comment: @CristiFati no i meant the comma, we are being told to use that to defend against sql attacks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you very much, is there any chance you could be able to tell me why whenever i input something i dont get any output (my error message pops up ) and there are no other errors popping up like before

Comment: @AidanCronin: shouldn't you `print result`? Or any other way to return it to the client?

Comment: yes one second ill send you a picture because when i enter the code into the overflow editor its compressed af, I am printing the result btw

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ive added a picture there , thank you

Comment: Change your DB password as soon as possible,  revision history of the question will keep trace of the old "connection = db.connect(" before the update

Comment: The comma is meant to be used inside `cursor.execute` to pass the arguments as a function argument. Not only are actually using `%` like you're saying you were told not to, but it's all inside triple quotes so everything is actually just a string literal. SQL is not involved in `'<tr><td>%s</td></tr>'` and you need to use `%` there.

Comment: @ASTEFANI already on it, noticed my blunder a bit too late...

Comment: @AlexHall ive done all of that but still no output? any suggestion as to why ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input>` is named `year` but you try to run `escape(form_data.getfirst('theyear'))`. `getfirst` returns `None` when there is no corresponding form value and `escape` fails one `None`. For similar reasons you need to better handle optional fields like what Willem said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error code:

```
/users/2020/adc2/public_html/cgi-bin/lab7/index.py in ()
     24     try:
     25         actor=escape(form_data.getfirst('actor'))
=>   26         genre=escape(form_data.getfirst('genre'))
     27         theyear=escape(form_data.getfirst('theyear'))
     28         director=escape(form_data.getfirst('director'))
genre = '', escape = <function escape>, form_data = FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('actor', 'i')]), form_data.getfirst = <bound method FieldStorage.getfirst of FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('actor', 'i')])>
 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/cgi.py in escape(s=None, quote=None)
   1038     warn("cgi.escape is deprecated, use html.escape instead",
   1039          DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
=> 1040     s = s.replace("&", "&amp;") # Must be done first!
   1041     s = s.replace("<", "&lt;")
   1042     s = s.replace(">", "&gt;")
s = None, s.replace undefined
```

escape() seems to get None as an argument. Escape() uses replace() directly internally, according to the given code snippet.. So the quick fix would be to make sure that you do not give None into the escape method but maybe an empty string instead.

```
my_non_none_value = form_data.getfirst('actor') if form_data.getfirst('actor') else ""
bla = escape(my_non_none_value)
```

long version:

```
my_non_none_value = form_data.getfirst('actor')
if my_non_none_value is None:
    my_non_none_value = ""
bla = escape(my_non_none_value)
```

Side note: escape() in cgi is deprecated, use html.escape() instead.

Comment: That's not how the ternary operator is done in Python, and also `or` would suffice as Willem suggested.

Comment: @AlexHall You are right. Typed that while working on other code (java). Corrected the example accordingly. Ore suffices, but for explaining the problem, I prefern longer code.